# How do moderator review queues differ from ours?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities

How do moderator queues differ from the 20k review queues (apart from getting a few extra like comment review queues)? Do moderators still get review audits, for example? Do they get the same (or similar) VLQ and close vote queues that we do?

How frequently do moderators tend to work the "lesser mortal" queues like VLQ, close vote, first post, or (*shudder*) triage queues?

Comment: There are no special moderator review queues. We have piles of *flags*, and no, there are no audits among those.

Comment: We still have access to the normal review queues, and are still subject to audits there if we do do reviews. I personally don't do reviews there, too busy with flags.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is one audit for mods, we do get a few "why was this declined" questions which ask us to Stop! Look and listen.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Lots of Q's there...

> (apart from getting a few extra like comment review queues)?*

There's quite a few more queues but yes. Anything flagged "other" goes to mods to review.

> Do moderators still get review audits, for example?*

Yes - and technically we can get review banned as any other user does for failing to pay attention. We see the same audit as you do and the system doesn't distinguish between having a diamond or not.

> Do they get the same (or similar) VLQ and close vote queues that we do?*

Yes. Anything flagged as NAA/VLQ goes into the appropriate queue, when that overflows mods can act on it if needs be. There's a deliberate delay of 1hr where it's in the community queue, and after that it's in the mod queue as well.

> How frequently do moderators tend to work the "lesser mortal" queues like VLQ, close vote, first post, or (shudder) triage queues?*

It's up to the moderator themselves.

I think I once tried going "all out" on the CV queue for instance, after 100 or so close votes, I just gave up.

Our focus is mainly on users and flags that the community can't do themselves. Be that chasing up sock-puppets, informing the CM team we feel votes should be invalidated, deleting accounts as necessary etc...

Comment: I assume that if you vote in a queue it's instantly binding, though, right?

Comment: @EJoshuaS correct. All mod votes (be they close/delete/flagging as spam) are binding and take effect immediately. There's also no limit on the amount of reviews/close/delete votes in a day.

Comment: Are you still limited to 40 items in the close vote queue?

Comment: @EJoshuaS nope. All review queues are unlimited.

Comment: This can lead to a bit of a catch-22: if someone is a high-throughput reviewer and wants to do more, they might think to become moderators in order to get rid of review limits. But then they wouldn't have the time to do all those regular reviews (not to mention that the duty of mods is outside the regular queues).